# How to filter based on list returned by map param using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java stream to filter some values based on certain conditions. I am able to achieve the same using traditional for loops and a little bit of streams, but I want to rewrite the same logic fully in streams.

**Original code:**

```
public List <String> getProductNames(Hub hub, String requestedGroup) {

    List <SupportedProduct> configuredProducts = repo.getSupportedProducts(hub);

    List <String> productNames = new ArrayList <> ();

    for (SupportedProduct supportedProduct: configuredProducts) {
        List < String > categoryNameList = new ArrayList <> ();
        String activeCategoryName = supportedProduct.getCategoryDetails().getActiveCategoryName();
        if (activeCategoryName == null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(supportedProduct.getCategoryDetails().getCategories())
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .forEach(category - > categoryNameList.add(category.getName()));
        } else {
            categoryNameList.add(activeCategoryName);
        }
        for (String catName: categoryNameList) {
            Division division = divisionRepo.getDivisionByCatName(catName);
            if (division != null && division.getGroup() == requestedGroup) {
                productNames.add(supportedProduct.getProductName());
            }
        }
    }

    return productNames;

}
```

**My try:**

```
return Optional.ofNullable(configuredProducts).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                .map(supportedProduct -> {
                    List<String> categoryNameList = new ArrayList<>();

                    String activeCategoryName = supportedProduct.getCategoryDetails().getActiveCategoryName();

                    if (activeCategoryName == null) {
                        Optional.ofNullable(supportedProduct.getCategoryDetails().getCategories())
                                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                                .forEach(category -> categoryNameList.add(category.getName()));
                    } else {
                        categoryNameList.add(activeCategoryName);
                    }
                    return categoryNameList;
                })
                .filter(catName ->{
                    Division division = divisionRepo.getDivisionByCatName(catName);
                    return division != null && division.getGroup() == requestedGroup;
                })........
```

But I'm lost beyond this.

Please help me to write the same using streams.

**EDIT:** Added IDEOne for testing - [Link](https://ideone.com/eImjyb)

Answer (score 2):

The logic inside is quite complicated, however, try this out:

```
public List <String> getProductNames(Hub hub, String requestedGroup) {
    List<SupportedProduct> configuredProducts = repo.getSupportedProducts(hub);

    // extract pairs: 
    //    key=SupportedProduct::getProductName
    //    values=List with one activeCategoryName OR names of all the categories
    Map<String, List<String>> namedActiveCategoryNamesMap = configuredProducts.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                SupportedProduct::getProductName,
                p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getCategoryDetails().getActiveCategoryName())
                        .map(Collections::singletonList)
                        .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(p.getCategoryDetails().getCategories())
                                        .stream()
                                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                        .map(Category::getName)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

    // look-up based on the categories' names, group equality comparison and returning a List
    return namedActiveCategoryNamesMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                .map(catName -> divisionRepo.getDivisionByCatName(catName))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(Division::getGroup)
                .anyMatch(requestedGroup::equals))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

- I recommend splitting into separate methods for sake of readability (**the best way to go**).
- The verbose logics of `Optional` chains including two `orElse` calls can be surely simplified, however, it gives you the idea.

---

- You can perform within one Stream using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`. In that case, I'd extract the `Function finisher` elsewhere, example:

```
public List<String> getProductNames(Hub hub, String requestedGroup) {
    return repo.getSupportedProducts(hub).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            SupportedProduct::getProductName,
                            categoryNamesFunction()),
                    productNamesFunction(requestedGroup)));
}
```

```
private Function<Map<String, List<String>>, List<String>> productNamesFunction(String requestedGroup) {
    return map -> map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                    .map(divisionRepo::getDivisionByCatName)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(Division::getGroup)
                    .anyMatch(requestedGroup::equals))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

```
private Function<SupportedProduct, List<String>> categoryNamesFunction() {
    return p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getCategoryDetails().getActiveCategoryName())
            .map(Collections::singletonList)
            .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(p.getCategoryDetails().getCategories())
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .map(Category::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Thank you for this. I will learn and try this out. ( I’ve never seen streams being used like this anywhere :) )

Comment: I haven't tested the code as long as I don't know the classes structure and have no data to test on. The purpose of this answer is to give you an idea how you can approach to the problem using Java Stream API. You might need to customize/fix/edit some parts, though.

Comment: No problem. I just needed a starting point and your answer helps a lot. Will test the solution in a hour (just stepped away) and will report back.

Comment: Just tried this solution, the `.stream()` call on the list in the `toMap` call doesn't seem to work as the `Optional.ofNullable` does not return a stream.

Comment: I'm trying to get an IDEone snippet ready for your testing